# I can no longer run the app on the Android emulator after the release build of the Flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I wanted to release the Flutter app,
and after running the release build to generate the aap file,
I pressed the green triangle run button in Android Studio and ran the app on the Android emulator.
I just saw the following log ,
then no matter how long it took, the app didn't start at all.
When I ran it on the actual iphone, it ran normally.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
```

Since it can be executed on the iphone,
I thought that it was caused by the Android emulator,
so I downloaded another emulator (Nexus 6 API 30) and ran it, but the result was still the same.

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest

What comes to mind is that I changed the "package name" and "android: label" in AndroidManifest.xml for the release build,
as described on the above page.
However, this step is absolutely necessary, so I don't think this is the cause.

Also, since I'm using firebase,
root / android / app / google-services.json
in the above file's "package_name" have been changed.
Is there any work required on the firebase side along with this?
Doesn't matter?
Other than that, I can't think of anything at all.

Comment: Are you sure it's not crashing as soon as the app is launched? As you're saying you changed the package name in the manifest file only but change is required in the app level build.gradle file and if you're using any Google dependencies you also need to sync and use the latest Google.json file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm sorry, I've already changed the app level build.gradle file.

When I look at the settings of the connected android app on the firebase console, the "package name" displayed on the console screen is "com.example.oldProjectName", that is, the old package name before the change, but I Need to change this?
I don't know how to change it, but where can I find it?

Comment: yes, change it and add the updated google.json file also check the ide console tab for any crash/ error messages

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I deleted the old app connected to firebase and created a new "package name" app, but the app still doesn't start.
Is the way to change the package name wrong?
I can't find a very specific procedure when I google, is there somewhere?

Comment: Actually, it might be something else that's causing the problem. Can't help without an error message.

Comment: I will try various things to isolate the problem a little more.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question